# This app is not authorized to use firebase authentication SH1 ,SH256

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, runtime-error

[I'm facing this issue . when i try to use my app by just running from android studio it's work well , but when i create this app for publishing and install on my smartphone , it's show this dialog . I had double checked my S1 and SH256 code , both are correct . I tried every thing but i couldn't . If anyone can help me to solve this issue then please help me .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evdgQ.png)

error : This app is not authorized to use firebase authentication.Please verify that the correct package name ans SH-1 and configure in the FireBase console.[A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the FireBase console . Please make sure this application's packageName/SHA256 pair registerd in the firebase console .]

Comment: Please paste the text of the error message into the question.

Comment: its not showing any error in studio , its showing error when i build apk to publish.

Comment: above text has image too , click and watch

Comment: I know that, I saw the picture. However, please put the text of the error into the question rather than using an image.

Comment: ok show i have to write exact error which is showing on app ?